# How get all links from website using CsQuery?

Tags: c#, jquery, parsing, html-parsing, csquery

I try get all links from website.

```
 var dom = CQ.CreateFromUrl("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow");
            CQ hrefs = dom.Select("a");

            foreach (var href in hrefs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(href);
            }
```

And I can't get only link(value of href). Please for help.

Answer (score 0):

If it is for wikis like wikipedia only, you might have a look at [the wikimedia api](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=parse&format=json&page=Stack%20Overflow&prop=links%7Cexternallinks).

Answer (score 0):

How about  `dom.Select("a").Where(x=>x.Contains('href'))`

or something similiar.